# Git config to not automerge when there are conflicts

Tags: git

When merging (or rebasing) a branch into (or onto) another, git usually tries to be smart and automatically merges changes if it can. It will show conflicts only when it can't automatically merge commits. However, this automerge isn't always right. Especially, if there are multiple changes within a single file git will automerge a few of them and show merge conflicts in others. This usually doesn't work very well because those other changes (that git automerged) are related to the conflicting changes and so you need to consider the entire changeset while fixing the conflict. But if git has automerged those changes you won't even notice that while fixing the conflict.

To avoid above situation I would like to know if there is a way to tell git (that during a merge or rebase) do not automerge anything in a file which has a conflict?

Comment: You can always get both versions of the file with `checkout --theirs` and `checkout --ours` (or `show :1:path`/`show :2:path`/`show :3:path`). Would that help? Perhaps a custom merge driver could help too

Comment: Yeah, I can do that but merge process becomes too complicated in that case. Maybe a custom merge driver can automate this. Though I have no clue how to write a merge driver. I thought this would a common requirement and so git would have a config option for this.

Answer (score 1):

> Especially, if there are multiple changes within a single file git will automerge a few of them and show merge conflicts in others

I totally know exactly what you mean. You can wind up with your code in the wrong method!

But no, there's nothing you can do. You just have to read really carefully when you to the merge conflict resolution. It will help a *lot* if you turn on the 3-way diff option:

```
merge.conflictstyle=diff3
```

This shows you what both wings of the merge started with (the merge base), so you can see what each is trying to do it. This will help you work out what needs changing as you resolve the merge.

Comment: Yeah I am already using the `diff3` conflict style. But that's not the same as showing all changes. One other way is to always open every single merge conflict with git mergetool (rather than opening it in whichever editor/IDE that you are working on). But again that's too cumbersome. I wonder if git maintainers would be open to the idea of adding this config option.

Comment: The problem here, though, is that you're heading down a slippery slope. The other day I had an issue where after the automerge a file wouldn't compile, because one of us had written an extension on a class and the other of us had renamed the class. There was _no_ merge conflict but the resulting file was broken. If you don't want that kind of thing ever to happen, you can _never_ automerge. In other words, it isn't merge conflicts that cause the problem you're now describing; it's automerge itself. Are you really willing to throw that away?

Comment: Anyway, this is why you have unit tests on absolutely everything. If automerge breaks your project, then if it compiles and runs, the tests catch it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your merge tool's doing. Use one that shows you all four versions (base, our, theirs, so-far) like `vimdiff` does and you see everything, including the proposed automerges and where they came from.